# How to get none if my function is called with no arguements in python?

Tags: python, function

Hey everyone i would like to ask how can I get null if my function is called with no arguments (`sum_func()`)?

```
def sum_func(*args):
       k = 0
       for i in args:
           k += i
       return k
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you understand as *function is empty*?

Comment: Pls format the code properly. I think what you want is to return "None" ?

Comment: Terminology is very important in programming. Python is not C. The "*null*" you refer to is called `None` in Python. And, "*if my function is empty*" makes no sense. Please reword your question.

Comment: The excersise ask to return null if the func is empty.

Comment: Mathematically, the function is now correct. Do you really need to break that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for nullity of argument `args` and return `None` as:

```
def sum_func(*args):
    if not args:
        return None

    k = 0
    for i in args:
        k += i
    return k

print(sum_func())
print(sum_func(2, 3))
```

Output:

```
None
5
```

You could also consider using ‘len(args)‘ and check if it is zero in case the input is of type boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to return `None` (not `Null`) if you don't pass any argument to the function, which can be done by checking the `args` as shown in the code below:

```
def sum_func(*args):
    if args:
        k = 0
        for i in args:
            k += i
        return k
    else:
        return None

print("With arguments:", sum_func(1, 2))
print("Without arguments:", sum_func())
```

Output:

```
With arguments: 3
Without arguments: None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if k!=0:
    return k
```

This is assuming you do not want to use count 0.

The function will return None if no return value given.